# can't figure out how to use distinct() django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

Help me please remove duplicates from my output:

## views.py

```
if request.is_ajax():
        subjects = Subjects.objects.distinct().order_by('-num_of_followers')[:5]
        result = serializers.serialize("json", subjects)
```

As you can see `distinct()` doesn't do anything.

My output right now looks like this:

```
aaa
aaa
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

but I want it to be like this:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

## UPDATED

right now my database looks like this:

```
Database changed
mysql> SELECT * FROM school_subjects;
+----+----------+---------+------------+---------------------+------------------+
| id | name     | user_id | created_by | created_time        | num_of_followers |
+----+----------+---------+------------+---------------------+------------------+
|  1 | Math 140 |       1 | rrr        | 2012-08-23 12:11:55 |                4 |
|  2 | lll      |       2 | aaa        | 2012-08-23 14:25:13 |                2 |
|  3 | kmkk     |       2 | aaa        | 2012-08-25 14:11:42 |                2 |
|  4 | llll     |       2 | aaa        | 2012-08-25 14:11:57 |                2 |
|  5 | Math 140 |       3 | qqq        | 2012-08-25 15:29:44 |                4 |
|  6 | qweqw    |       3 | qqq        | 2012-08-25 15:30:32 |                1 |
|  7 | lalala   |       3 | qqq        | 2012-08-25 15:38:57 |                1 |
|  8 | kkdkdk   |       3 | qqq        | 2012-08-25 17:49:25 |                1 |
|  9 | aaaa     |       2 | aaa        | 2012-08-27 19:13:49 |                1 |
| 10 | mmcmcm   |       2 | aaa        | 2012-08-27 19:22:10 |                1 |
| 11 | aaaaa    |       2 | aaa        | 2012-08-27 21:17:32 |                1 |
| 12 | Math 140 |       2 | aaa        | 2012-08-27 21:25:07 |                4 |
+----+----------+---------+------------+---------------------+------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## JSON that I'm getting:

```
[{"pk": 1, "model": "school.subjects", "fields": {"created_time": "2012-08-23 12:11:55", "num_of_followers": 4, "name": "Math 140", "created_by": "rrr", "user": 1}}, {"pk": 12, "model": "school.subjects", "fields": {"created_time": "2012-08-27 21:25:07", "num_of_followers": 4, "name": "Math 140", "created_by": "aaa", "user": 2}}, {"pk": 5, "model": "school.subjects", "fields": {"created_time": "2012-08-25 15:29:44", "num_of_followers": 4, "name": "Math 140", "created_by": "qqq", "user": 3}}, {"pk": 4, "model": "school.subjects", "fields": {"created_time": "2012-08-25 14:11:57", "num_of_followers": 2, "name": "llll", "created_by": "aaa", "user": 2}}, {"pk": 3, "model": "school.subjects", "fields": {"created_time": "2012-08-25 14:11:42", "num_of_followers": 2, "name": "kmkk", "created_by": "aaa", "user": 2}}]
```

from this example you can see that I'm getting Math 140 3 times, but I want it to appear only once.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs have [some specific information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) about using `distinct` and how its affected by the use of `order_by`

Try switching the order, and also specifying the field:

```
Subjects.objects.order_by('created_by', '-num_of_followers')\
    .distinct('created_by')[:5]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didin't work! I was trying to follow API and did exactly the same thing,but nothing happend

Comment: one more question:  if I have only 3 entries in my database, and 2 of them are Math 140, the result is Math 140 (two times) and than another entry

Comment: Then add 'name' either before or after the 'created_by' in both `order_by` and `distinct`

Comment: The problem is, django gives me an error that distinct() takes one argument......

Comment: I even tried to just perform a raw query, and do something like this: SELECT DISTINCT name FROM school_subjects ORDER BY num_of_followers DESC;, using the connection.cursor but PyDev does not recognize cursor()

Comment: What ver of django are you using?

Comment: it is 1.3 version of Django and Python version is 2.7.2+

Comment: You need django 1.4 for multiple distinct field values. I think right now it is probably ignoring whatever you were passing to distinct, as in 1.3 it takes no arguments.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I noticed that, will download Django 1.4 =))) Thank you jdi for all your answers!!!